# 3.5inch screen cannot accommodate all subviews

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, xcode6.1, size-classes

I have 3 labels .First one at the top of the screen, second in the middle and third below. I used both( size class(cW rH)+ autolayout)to layout the labels.The third label **appears in all sizes expect the 3.5inch screen**. Can **autolayout and/or size class** help me accommodate my third label in some way?.I know putting a scroll view or doing programatically will help me achieve what i want but just want to know whether the current iOS SDK is intelligent enough to cut this.

Comment: you need to start from hAwA for autolayout....for good practice

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too and u can accept it too

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different constraint for each label.

Please check below screenshot to understand how to set constraint to each label.[image]

May be it will help you to set labels.

Answer (score 0):

I have Submit label as third label and I did following for it . Try using it and dont forget to click add constraint after doing it
[image]

[image]